# Converting 1-minute market data into 5-minute data

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

This is the data frame I have:

[image: 1]

This is how I need it to be:

[image: 2]

This is what `.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min')).agg({"open": "first", "high": "max", "low": "min", "close": "last", "volume": "sum"})` gives me:

[image: 3]

1. I understand that data with 5-minute intervals can instead be procured, but that would defeat the purpose of me trying to get a little better at python.
2. I intend to replicate this procedure at (10, 15, 30)-minute timeframes on the same data.
3. This should provide a similar data frame, only with different values:

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
data = yf.download("INFY.NS", end = dt.datetime.today(), start = dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(days=1), interval="1m")
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data = data.between_time('09:31','15:30')
```

Directives on ways to paste python data frames are welcome.

**EDIT:** Adding replicable code and some clarity (and a solve!)

1. I intend to group the dataframe below to 5-min frequencies:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
date = pd.to_datetime(['9:31', '9:32', '9:33', '9:34', '9:35', '9:36', '9:37', '9:38', '9:39', '9:40'])
a = pd.DataFrame({'Open': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  'High': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  'Low': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                  'Close': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                  'Volume': [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]}, index  = date)
```

2. I tried to use pandas.Grouper as below, but it would aggregate data to a different bucket:

```py
a.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min')).agg({"Open": "first", "High": "max", "Low": "min", "Close": "last", "Volume": "sum"})
```

3. With this, data indexed [09:31 - 09:34] is grouped/aggregated to a single row indexed [09:30]; however, I need data indexed [09:31-09:35] to be grouped to [09:35]
4. A solution I found, thanks to @Daniel Weigel and pandas documentation:

```py
b = a.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min',origin='start',label='right')).agg({"Open": "first", "High": "max", "Low": "min", "Close": "last", "Volume": "sum"})
b.index += pd.Timedelta(minutes=-1)
```

Welcome any suggestions/modifications to improve the solution! :)

Comment: "...ways to paste python data frames..." Have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and please [edit] your question to show sample data as text rather than an image

Comment: Thank you and @enke for your assistance and suggestions. I did try to have the images inline instead of as links at the outset, but I lacked the know-how and a supposed exigency meant I couldn't research well enough. I have edited the question with replicable code now - along with a solution I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your issue, but why dont you change the index timestamp after your grouper operation ?
Something like

```
tmp.index=tmp.index.floor(freq='5min')+pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)
```

So you make sure to floor your existing timestamp to the nearest 5 minutes of the bottom, then add 5 minutes to that..and same method for other frequencies.
So with your existing code, that is

```
tmp=data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min')).agg({"Open": "first", "High": "max", "Low": "min", "Close": "last", "Volume": "sum"})

tmp.index=tmp.index.floor(freq='5min')+pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)
tmp
```

Comment: Thank you! There was an additional issue with how the data was aggregated/grouped along with the index's TimeDelta, and that was an additional cause for concern. Reading through some pandas.Grouper documentation, I could arrive at a possible solution that I have appended to the original question. Thank you for taking the time to respond to what was/is a poorly worded question.